# "org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2" maven plugin showed error in eclipse

Tags: java, web-services, maven-3

I want to use "org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2" maven plugin to generate class from web service. but is showed error like below in eclipse:

```
Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate failed: 
A required class was missing while executing org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate: com/sun/xml/bind/api/ErrorListener
```

below is the pom snippet:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
        <generatePackage>fpcy.wsdl</generatePackage>
        <schemas>
            <schema>
                <url>{the web sevice url}</url>
            </schema>
        </schemas>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

and jre configuration:
[image]

but how can I add this class into my project?

Comment: First thought is that you don't have the dependencies for the plugin configured correctly, but your question doesn't really contain enough information to answer.
1) does it work when you run mvn from the command line.
2) post the at least the plugin config ideally the whole pom.xml

Comment: 1)use m2eclipse, no other errors except this. 2)added the snippet of pom.xml @lscoughlin

Comment: it seems that your JAVA_HOME is pointing to a JRE and not to a JDK

Comment: jre conifguration in eclipse is pointing to the jdk path@SuganthanMadhavanPillai

Answer (score 2):

I find the way to solve it by my own:
change the jaxb plugin artifactid from "maven-jaxb2-plugin" to "maven-jaxb20-plugin". Please refer to [Using-a-Specific-JAXB-Version](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Using-a-Specific-JAXB-Version)